# MATLAB - How to plot recursion values?

Tags: matlab, recursion, plot

I have a simple function f(x) = 2.5x * (1-x) that I want to plot values for recursively. I succeeded in developing a recursive function but do not know how to extract the recursion values to plot on a graph.

```
function [y] = orbits(x)
y = 2.5 * x .* (1 - x);
if x == 0
    y = 0;
else
    y = orbits(y)
end
```

I would largely appreciate any help as I am new to programming and being able to plot this function would help me a lot.

e.g.

```
>> orbits(0.1)
```

x =
    0.1000
x =
    0.2250
x =
    0.4359
x =
    0.6147

How do I extract those x's to plot?

Thanks!

Comment: All I want to know, whether it is possible to plot the recursion values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate the results over the recursion. I added another parameter `epsilon` which determines when to stop the recursion:

```
function [y] = orbits(x,epsilon)
    y = 2.5 * x .* (1 - x);
    if abs(y-x) < epsilon
        y = [];
    else
        y = [y,orbits(y,epsilon)];
    end
end
```

Demo:

```
>>values = orbits(0.1,0.00001)

values =

  Columns 1 through 10

    0.2250    0.4359    0.6147    0.5921    0.6038    0.5981    0.6010    0.5995    0.6002    0.5999

  Columns 11 through 15

    0.6001    0.6000    0.6000    0.6000    0.6000

>>plot(values)
```

[image: value plot]